# Empty .NET Core 2.0 project with MVC template in Visual studio 2017

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, .net-core

Today I migrated from Visual studio 2015 to Visual studio 2017.

In visual studio 2015 whenever I wanted to create a new web project not only was I able to choose it as an empty project but also I was able to indicate my empty project be in which template by clicking on diverse check boxes in `new project window`. For example I was able to create a MVC project which all folders were empty.

I can not find this facilities in Visual studio 2017. If I choose a MVC project in `new project windows` it creates some default styles, views, and controller which I don't like. If I choose empty project then it don't have Model,View and Controller folders either.

So am I able to create an `Empty` + `MVC` + `.Net Core 2` project in Visual studio 2017 or Microsoft simply removed this feature?

**UPDATE**

I have tried to first create an empty project and then add MVC to it by installing `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` through `NUGET`. But it just added MVC dependencies to my project. Am I have to create all needed folders (model, view, controller, shared....) manually? Its really frustrating.

I believe I have installed .NET Core properly. This screenshot of my `New project window` is a proof of that.

[image]

Comment: This is definitely still possible in .NETCore 2. Ensure you have the .NETCore 2+ SDK installed. You should already be on VS 15.5.6 if you installed VS2017 moments ago.

Comment: @Ethane I believe I have installed .NET Core properly. See my update

Comment: If you create an empty project, then it wont add any ASP NET Core dependencies, as it's empty. However, if you want to use all of the ASP NET Core MVC and EF Core stuff, then you can add a reference to the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.All](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All/) metapackage, and it will pull most of the stuff you might need. You'll need to wire it all up, but the packages will all be there